# could not parse json error instamojo

Tags: ios, swift, instamojo

I have integrated instamojo payment gateway in my iOS application. I am currently using Xcode 9.2 with swift 4.0. I have installed latest SDK through Cocoapods.
I have also setup access token url on my server.

but when i initiate a payment by using the code provided by Instamojo. the resultant status was false and i got error message "could not parse json"

```
IMConfiguration.sharedInstance.setupOrder(purpose: "buying", buyerName: "Shardul", emailId: "tester@gmail.com", mobile: "7875432991", amount: "20", environment: .Test, on: self) { (success, message) in
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 1, execute: {
                if success {
                   print(message)
                } else {
                   print(message)
                }
            })
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have implemented everything correctly, then it must work. 
Have you checked you access token php script on your server.

Comment: Then look at your server end. You need all the 4 information including access token and bearer .

Comment: Ohh thanks bro. I was only sending access token from the backend . 
Now i send the whole dictionary and it worked. :)